# Load Date from Access database to listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, load

I am using following query to add date into ms access database. The format of DATEANDTIME is Date/Time in the ms access file

```
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 (DATEANDTIME) values ('" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "')"
        accessCommand.CommandText = strSQL
            accessCommand.Connection = accessConnection
            accessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            accessCommand.Dispose()
        accessDataReader.Close()
        MsgBox("OK Done")
```

Access file snapshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FcAg.png)

Now i am using following query to fetch data from ms access database to ListViewLOCATION in vb.net

```
 strSQL = "SELECT * from Table1 WHERE DATEANDTIME>='" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "' and DATEANDTIME <='" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString & "'"
        accessCommand.CommandText = strSQL
        accessCommand.Connection = accessConnection
        accessAdopter.SelectCommand = accessCommand
        accessDataReader = accessCommand.ExecuteReader
        ListViewLOCATION.Items.Clear()
        While (accessDataReader.Read())
            ListViewLOCATION.Items.Add(accessDataReader("DATEANDTIME"))
        End While
        accessCommand.Dispose()
        accessDataReader.Close()
```

but showing this error

Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Please help me to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*DateTime* in Access is not text.

So, use a *formatted text expression* for the date value:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 (DATEANDTIME) Values (#" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#)"
```

Likewise for the comparison/filtering.